# Make Array From Checkbox

Tags: php

I wan't to make an array from checkbox.

I've use `array($_POST[test],$_POST[test1],$_POST[test2])`
It works, but if once of array is NULL the array also NULL

So what I wan't is if once of array is NULL, it's not in array

Like this

```
$_POST['test']=NULL;
$_POST['test1']="ARAAY1";
$_POST['test2']="ARRAY2";
```

and it will be `array($_POST[test1],$_POST[test2])`

Answer (score 4):

try something like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="one"/> one<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="tow"/> tow<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="three"/> three<br/>



$checked = $_POST['options'];
for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
    echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: No, I don't mean it

I want to make an array, no to echo that. I want save that to a variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_null()` to check if a value is `NULL` or `isset()` to check that it is set and not NULL. Then you can append that variable to the array if and only if it isn't `NULL`.

Even better do what @NullPointer has in their answer where you set up the form so that the checkbox values come in as an array to begin with.